# How do you represent an axis as a vector?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

I am Alice.

In a question I am doing, it requires me to find the directional derivative of function $f$ at $(2, 3, 4)$ , in the direction of positive $z$ axis.

So I trying to figure out, how to represent an axis as a vector in general. In case, I want the positive $z$, how can I do that?

$z = (0, 0, 1)$ Would this suffice? Why? I don't understand. Thanks all.

Comment: Yes, $(0,0,1)$ would suffice.

Comment: Since only the direction matters and $(0,0,1)$ has the desired direction (z-axis), $(0,0,1)$ is a valid choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An axis is nothing more than the extension of a unit vector in a specific direction. In your case, you are using rectangular coordinates, so the unit vectors are referred to some "privileged" directions:

- the unit vector for the $x$ axis is $\mathbf{\hat{x}} = (1,0,0)$;
- the unit vector for the $y$ axis is $\mathbf{\hat{y}} = (0,1,0)$;
- the unit vector for the $z$ axis is $\mathbf{\hat{z}} = (0,0,1)$.

These unit vectors identify the directions of the related axes.

In a directional derivative, only the direction matters, as pointed out in the comments, so your guess is right: you can consider the direction of the positive $z$ axis simply as $(0,0,1)$.